# Can you integrate Google Messaging into your own app?

Tags: android, message, messaging

I'm wondering if you can use any of the available Google messaging app (Android messages, duo, allo etc.) in your own Android app? I have found no information on it at all.

Similarly like Facebook Messages which can be integrated.

Thanks

Comment: you can take a reference form below mentioned link--> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: @yash786 I don't think that he means that type of messaging. He means "real" messages from "real" people through a messenger app.

Comment: Cloud Messaging is about sending push notifications, not a messenger integration.

Comment: @breakline for sending push notifications you can refer the above mentioned link

Answer (score 1):

There's no official support for that but many IM apps support Hangout integration as it is based on XMPP protocol. There are Java libs that support that so you way want to check them out.

Comment: Hangouts is actually abandoned. Also, XMPP is problematic with Hangouts, it's not pure XMPP standard and some things may not work.

Comment: Abandoned? This is IT board so either you back your claims with facts, links to official docs/statements, or stay quiet instead of spreading BS.